# WebkitAnimationEnd event of jquery. How to set Background unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using webkitAnimationEnd for my page to Animate whole page from bootom to top. While happening animation there is black backround is coming for a while.. that background is my previous page from which i am starting animation. That background is clickable. Can any one tell me how to set my that black background unclickable while animation occures?

Comment: Could you provide relevant code of click handler and HTML of relative animated element?

Comment: Sorry A. Wolff. code i cant :(. But i will tell you what i am doing and what i want exactly. there is button and on click of button i am animating my next page. This animation occures from bottom to top. which takes 2 sec. while it goes on top there is black background i am looking. and if i click on that background my previous page (The button where i start animation) gets in front. All I want is to unclick that background..

Comment: I mean at least provide identifier (ID/class) of animated and clickable elements. But i don't see any reason you couldn't share basic code you are using

Comment: When this animation get started? Is this any specific event?

Comment: Yes jay.. There is button. On click of that button I am starting my animation.